# Selecting list element from bootstrap dropdown, showing selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have no idea how to write the javascript code for this, can someone help me please?

```
 <div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select one <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Investments</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">All of the Above</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder ="Years of experience" >
 </div>
</p>
```

Comment: what do you want to show when an item is selected

Comment: the selected item, so if you click on entrepreneurship on the drop down event, entrepreneurship should show as selected choice and button should go back up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a click handler to the `li` elements like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.input-group-btn .dropdown-menu > li:not(.divider)').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('ul').prev().text($(this).text())
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w4s8u/)

Comment: i need input box to be left alone, as the user will be putting a value inside, is it possible for the value to show up on the button instead?

Comment: Thank you! can you edit your answer so that future people looking for a similar solution can see it? cheers :)